# React Native wait for function to finish before proceed

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code:

```
const DuellScreen = () => {
...
 const [code, setCode] = useState("");
 const [keyExisting, setExi] = useState(true);
...
return (
...
 <BlockButton
                text="Apply"
                onPress={() => {
                  keyExists(code, setExi)
                  if (keyExisting == true) {
                    Alert.alert("Game joined");
                  } else if (keyExisting == false) {
                    Alert.alert(
                      "Game does not exist or someone has already joined"
                    );
                  }
                }}
              />
...)
```

My function `keyExists` is working with firebase/firestore, so probably it takes a while until `keyExisting` is updated.
This leads to a wrong outcome of my if statement.
A sign for this is also, that with the first press on the button the if statement is always "true" because thats the initial state. If i change the initial state to "false", the outcome of the if statement after the first button click is always "false".
So the first click on the button is always the initial state(useState), but it should be updated right before the if statement...

Heres also my keyExists function, if needed:

```
export const keyExists = (setKey, keyExi) => {
  duettsRef
    .where("key", "==", setKey)
    .where("player1", "!=", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .where("player2", "==", "")
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      keyExi(!querySnapshot.empty);
      if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
        querySnapshot.docs[0].ref.update({
          player2: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You wan you wait until your function complete right ?
You can use promise for that to wait the code to execute your function and then continue.

Let me know if I am in right direction, I can help you more in this.

Comment: @DipanSharma Yes thats correct. I would be very grateful for more help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing several things here.

The firebase SDK is asynchronous, so the functions you are calling return a promise.
You have two ways to consume a promise, you can either use it with a .then .catch statement or you can use it inside an asynchronous function with the keyword await.

Your code is doing something quite odd and potentially wrong: you are giving your `keyExists` function a setter from a `useState` hook, and you are hoping to use this value directly after calling your keyExists, this is not possible.
Your statement `if (keyExisting == true)` will be executed before your code reach `.then((querySnapshot)`.

Your hook here `const [keyExisting, setExi] = useState(true);` is giving you a value and a setter, when you use `setExi` setter you are doing two things : 1- setting the value of `keyExisting` for the next render 2- triggering a new render of your component. If you have a function where you call `setExi` and then use `keyExisting` it will still have the previous value before you set the new one.

You could do something like this:

```
const DuellScreen = () => {
...
 const [code, setCode] = useState("");
 const [keyExisting, setExi] = useState(true);
...
return (
...
 <BlockButton
                text="Apply"
                onPress={async () => {
                  try {
                    const exist = await keyExists(code);
                    if (exist == true) {
                      Alert.alert("Game joined");
                    } else if (keyExisting == false) {
                      Alert.alert(
                        "Game does not exist or someone has already joined"
                      );
                    }
                  } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e)
                  }
                }}
              />
...)

export const keyExists = (setKey, keyExi) => {
  return duettsRef
    .where("key", "==", setKey)
    .where("player1", "!=", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .where("player2", "==", "")
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      
      if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
        querySnapshot.docs[0].ref.update({
          player2: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
        });
      }

      return (!querySnapshot.empty);
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
};
```

But you should probably split your keyExists in two functions: one that only tell you if your key exist and another one that update your firestore database.
Another thing probably worth doing is using some kind of activity Indicator in order to lock your button, right know your use can click multiple times on your button and each click will trigger a new call to your keyExists function.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesnt work. I printed:  `const exist = await keyExists(code); console.log("EXIST: " + exist);` but its undefined.

Comment: Sorry, a return was missing in the above code.
You should return the whole firebase statement with a return inside the last .then, this should return a promise with your boolean value.

Anyway don't copy paste exactly the above but rather look at how promise works : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

This was a quick answer to give you an idea of what you could do to handle your async firestore calls.

Comment: No problem. I tried to split it into 2 functions now. Its working good except one thing. Its always returning "false"...                                                     
`var opponent = false;` then like above.... `.then((querySnapshot) => {if(!querySnapshot.empty){opponent = true; }})return opponent;};`